# Redirect all to base domain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect all pages like:

```
www.mydomain.com/test
www.mydomain.com/test2/test3
```

and so on ...

to always base

```
www.mydomain.com
```

How can i do this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,QSA,R=301]
```

wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that solution OK

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+$
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z].*)
RewriteRule .* http://kap.com/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the `RewriteCond`s and redirect everything to `/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.
Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Comment: if REQUEST_URI matches / than rewrite to / ?? its endless loop :( i've try it

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://www.mydomain.com/
```

It will redirect everything to your new domain.
This will work if you have [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)